# Python3: No module named dateutil

Tags: python-3.x, python-dateutil

I am unable to get dateutil installed in my Python code.

```
    from dateutil import tz 
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

I had date-util installed (Python version is 3.7.3)

```
> pip3 install python-dateutil
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.7.3)
```

I cannot uninstall them (to reinstall). I get the following error

```
> sudo pip3 uninstall python-dateutil
Not uninstalling python-dateutil at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'python-dateutil'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Then, I used the following command to uninstall:

```
> sudo apt-get remove  python3-dateutil #This worked
> pip3 install python-dateutil
```

This works, but asks me to install cycler, kiwisolver, pyparsing, which I install using pip3. But I still cant get the python code working - has the same error (ImportError: No module named dateutil)

Any suggestions on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - The python code is being called from a bash script. It worked fine until recently. Recently I installed some other packages that installed python 2.x. So, the python scripts were using Python 2.x rather than 3.x. I had symbolic links to python 3.x, but that didn't help.

Now, I am explicitly use `python3 mycode.py` to overcome this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend to use **conda** environment instead of **pip**. See, there are several modules which do not give expected behaviour in pip (like pytorch).

Get the package installed using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-dateutil
```

returning the question, to get the package running it requires fulfillment of it's dependencies. If you are using **python 3.7.3** its obvious that it may lack in some of the features of modern **python 3.11** as a result you get the obvious error. The python package `python-dateutil` must have been configured according to the modern python language version.

Iam using `python 3.11.1` and the package gets installed very perfectly. **You may install old version of package or upgrade your python language version or use Conda as mentioned before**.